# 502 Bad Gateway Issue - Using Nginx and Jenkins

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I'm facing a problem with one server mine. I have a configuration of a Jenkins application running under Nginx in a Ubuntu OS.

But after updating Jenkins to a new version, when I try to reach my Jenkins web application, I get this error:
"502 Bad Gateway - nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)"

Apparently all my configuration are okay.

How can I solve it?

Nginx error log:

```
2019/04/24 16:20:02 [error] 11424#11424: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: yyy.yy.yyy.yy, server: xx.xx.xxx.xxx, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "xx.xx.xxx.xxx", referrer: "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/"
```

Comment: is this mapped to any DNS service ?

Comment: according to `upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico`, you have nginx and jenkins install on same machine?  Can you show your nginx.conf? And confirm you can access jenkins directly without nignx.